# ObjectQuery lambda expression for select inside select

Tags: linq, lambda, objectquery

i want to create query like this using lambda expression in ObjectQuery

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE ID in (SELECT ID in tableB)
```

I try using

```
var histories = _entities.ProductViewHistories.Take(5).OrderByDescending(p=>p.DateViewed);
var products = _entities.Products.Where(p => p.ID in histories );
```

but it's not working.
Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - "in" isn't part of C# in that way. Try this though:

```
var products = _entities.Products.Where(p => histories.Contains(p.ID));
```

`Contains` is the appropriate method to detect whether a value is within another collection. However, you *may* find it would be more appropriate to use a join here.

Also, I'm concerned about this query:

That *doesn't* represent the 5 most recently viewed histories - it represents "some arbitrary 5 view histories" (the first 5 returned in some indeterminate order) then arranged in most-recent-first order.

I *suspect* you actually want:

```
var histories = _entities.ProductViewHistories.OrderByDescending(p=>p.DateViewed)
                                              .Take(5);
```